# OpenVPN without Root-CA

Tags: openvpn, certificate-authority

Simple OpenVPN Setup with SSL Authentication.

SSL-Setup: Root-CA > Intermediate-CA > Issuing-CA

All certificates (vpn-server and -clients) are issued by the "Issuing-CA".

I tried to use the certificate of the Issuing-CA as OpenVPN `ca ca.pem` parameter in the openvpn (server- and client-) config.

This did not work.

I had to add the complete certificate chain to the `ca.pem`.
Then it worked.

I thought the `ca` parameter specifies *trusted* CAs. I do not want to include the whole certificate chain since I do not see the necessity for this! Contrary - this seems dangerous to me - since the Root-CA and the Intermediate CA can issue certificates for CNs that are used in the VPN! I would classify this as a security risk.

Is there a way to set a trust anchor to a non-root-CA?

Comment: How did it "not work"? Please include client and server logs indicating any errors.

Comment: This is not the question. I found the problem and searching the internet (missed telling that, though...) indicates, that OpenVPN does certificate verification up to the root and does not view the ca parameter as trusted CA. Even if I might have made a mistake - my question is in the last sentence and needs no debugging of my verbose explanation.

Comment: Public keys are public and can be distributed freely. This is by design.

Comment: @Michael Hampton: Yes. But that does not cover all constraints given. And it's really no answer to my security concern mentioned.

Comment: It is an answer. The certificates (and the public keys they contain) are public by their nature. It's their private keys that are private; without those you can't sign anything.  I can go into any web browser and retrieve the trusted root certificates from all of the major CAs.

Comment: What do I have to clarify here? I do not talk about private keys here. But if I add the root-CA and intermediate-CA /public/-keys to my ca.pem - all certificates issued by them (with appropriate CNs) will also be accepted!

Comment: I think you're encountering a design decision by the OpenVPN team: you are meant to make a PKI for a given VPN.  This might be something to bring up in the OpenVPN forums.  I, for one, would be interested to know what you find.